# Reopen question bug

Tags: bug, vote-to-reopen

When reviewing a question to be reopened if you:

- Click reopen
- Cancel the confirmation dialog

You will now see additional information about the question including any comments that are normally hidden during the review process...

I suspect these details should always be hidden or (possibly better?) always be shown

<sub>Note: Discovered using Google Chrome - Version 37.0.2062.124 m on Windows</sub>

Image displaying issue - Before clicking on the left, after clicking on the right

[image]